# Cutting large diameter threads

Tags: pipe, plastic, cutting, copper-tubing, metal-cutting

I have an extensive tap & die set, but they're mainly designed for common bolt sizes.

The threads I need to cut are in (and on) metal and/or plastic pipes, or tubes; ranging between ∅49-89mm.

What's the proper way to cut these kinds of threads?

Comment: 'Metal' is vague - what type of metal? What kind of duty cycle are we talking; dozens a day for years, or do you just want a quick half-a-dozen?

Comment: That was intentional. I haven't settled on a material yet. It's not imperative that I use any one in particular, as long as it's fairly rigid (and available). It could even be PVC if that simplifies things. Whatever you might recommend ought to be appropriate. I suppose beggars can't be choosers; I'll take what I can get. Any information is likely to be useful at this point.

Comment: A quick half dozen would be a good start. It's not for mass production.

Comment: If you're using PVC why not just buy the pre-threaded stuff or cement it all together? Would help to have some context...

Comment: I'm not necessarily using PVC. I thought it would be a good idea, but I wasn't able to find the correct thread.

Comment: I'm guessing the metric sizes put you out of the US, but here the large home improvement chains will cut and thread pipe at no charge.  If you haven't already bought the pipe, asking the store first may prove profitable.

Comment: It seems like OP has an XY problem.  But these are basic building facts, so a good question.

Comment: More like an A→Z problem. Here in Australia, the major home hardware chain is called Bunnings Warehouse. Probably the closest thing to Lowe's or Home Depot in the US. Generally, whenever I go in there with a question (including this one), their eyes just glaze over, so I teach them some first day basics, and then I consult my peeps on the internet.

Answer (score 1):

An exceptionally brief search for "pipe threader" revealed many options. Hand sets for under $100, powered models are available at most tool rental places.

PVC and ABS pipe is typically glued (ok, solvent welded) together. Threading typical schedule 40 plastic will probably weaken it enough that you may as well just push the joints together.

Answer (score 0):

Cutting pipe is a completely different *type* of operation than cutting rod and bolts, with completely different techniques and tool sets.   Not least, the threads are tapered.

Here in the States, the go-to manufacturer for pipe threading is "Ridgid".  Can't speak for Europe.

The tools are fairly expensive, especially on large sizes .  The tools can be rented, or if you are are careful, you can get your pipe dimensions and have the hardware store cut the thread when they sell you the pipe.  You have to be very careful.

Treading is a heck of a lot of work.  I rarely see new work done in threaded pipe unless it really has to.  You may be better off transitioning into easier-to-work-with technology like plastic.

Some plastic pipe is threaded, but its purpose is either to transition to metal threaded pipe, or provide an easy point of separation.  This is done with adapters which already have correct threads molded into them, and then they cement onto regular plastic pipe.